# How to load file on scroll using javascript on element<ngx-monaco-diff-editor>?

Tags: javascript, angular, ajax, ngx-monaco-editor

I have been trying this for more than a week but have not been able to achieve it in angular. Can someone please take a look into it?

onContainerScroll() never gets called, I was wondering how to do it using javascript, on scroll this element and on reaching bottom call API with next range?

```
<ngx-monaco-diff-editor id="diffeditor" [options]="diffOptions" [originalModel]="originalModel" #elm
[modifiedModel]="modifiedModel" (scroll)="onContainerScroll($event)">
</ngx-monaco-diff-editor>

@ViewChild('elm', { read: ElementRef }) elm: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log(this.elm.nativeElement)  //return the ngx element
}
```

Comment: You could possibly solve it by getting a reference to the editor via `ViewChild`... It might expose some events you may need.

Comment: it shows undefined

Comment: You can use it in, or after `ngAfterViewInit` is called

Comment: I am able to get the element but how can to get the scroll event out of it?basically , I want to detect when it reaches the bottom and call API ...

Comment: You don't want to get the HTLM element but rather the component to access what it may offer to you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the reference to the `DiffEditorComponent` and then

```html
<ngx-monaco-diff-editor
  id="diffeditor"
  [options]="diffOptions"
  [originalModel]="originalModel"
  [modifiedModel]="modifiedModel">
</ngx-monaco-diff-editor>
```

```
@ViewChild(DiffEditorComponent) diffEditor: DiffEditorComponent;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(diffEditor._editorContainer); // HTMLElement that might be scrolled
}
```

You will have to dig deeper, but this is a reasonable start to go forth.